# How to disable the following button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have a hard time trying to disable the buttons I don't need in Tkinter, until some condition is met.

The following code it's a reference of what I'm doing:

```
ID_Personal=[]
ID_Product=[]

from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def addProduct():
    def callback():
            ID_Product.append(ID_Product_Entry.get())
            print("Product registered")
    
    windowProduct = Tk()
    lblProduct = Label(windowProduct, text="ID: ")
    lblProduct.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=0, column=0)
    
    ID_Product_Entry = Entry(windowProduct)
    ID_Product_Entry.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=0, column=1)
    
    btnAdd = Button(windowProduct, text="Submit",command=callback)
    btnAdd.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=1, column=0)
    windowProduct.mainloop()

def addPersonal():
    def callbackPersonal():
            ID_Personal.append(ID_Personal_Entry.get())
            print("Employee registered")
    
    windowPersonal = Tk()
    lblProduct = Label(windowPersonal, text="ID: ")
    lblProduct.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=0, column=0)

    ID_Personal_Entry = Entry(windowPersonal)
    ID_Personal_Entry.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=0, column=1)

    btnAddP = Button(windowPersonal, text="Submit",command=callbackPersonal)
    btnAddP.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=1, column=0)
    windowPersonal.mainloop()
    
btnProduct = Button(window,text="Product",command=addProduct)
btnProduct.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=0, column=0)
        
btnPersonal = Button(window,text="Personal",command=addPersonal)
btnPersonal.grid(padx=10, pady=10, row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Basically what I need to do is disable the button btnProduct when my ID_Personal list it's empty. Once some personal has been registered, then it must be active again. I've been trying but nothing seems to work. I don't know if I'm using the if condition wrongly or what. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can disable the button with the **state** option

Answer (score 0):

Set the state disabled when you create the button.

```py
btnProduct = Button(window,text="Product",command=addProduct, state="disabled")
```

And in the `callbackPersonal` function set the state active.

```py
btnProduct.config(state="active")
```

This way when you run the program the product button will be disabled, but once you add your first personal, the button will be active.

Comment: What if I have my button inside another function? I've tried this solution, but it keeps telling me "btnProduct" isn't assigned.

Comment: @AlexaMartínez This is another question then.

Comment: Well, I might got you wrong,. But basically  the btnProduct button isn't inside any function, so you can reach it from anywhere, except before you create it. If you want to edit a button that is created in a function, you can only do it inside the function, and after you created it. Suppose you want to disable the btnAdd button if your ID_Personal is empty. When you create the button you can set the state to "disabled" since your ID_Personal is empty and then write an if statement and change it to "active" when it's not empty. Sorry if this wasn't your question, i don't really understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the state of btnProduct to "disabled" when you create it, as the list ID_Personal is initially empty.

```
btnProduct = Button(window,text="Product",command=addProduct,state='disabled')
```

You can then change the button state to "normal" in the callbackPersonal function using `btnProduct.config(state='normal')`
This will normalize the button the first time an item is added to ID_Personal

Now if your app demands that the button should go back to "disabled" if ID_Personal is empty and turn "normal" only when ID_Personal is non-empty then the above solution won't work. In that case, we need to recursively update the widgets based on changing conditions. The "after" function can help us to achieve that.

```
def update():
    if len(ID_Personal) > 0:
        btnProduct.config(state='normal')
    else:
        btnProduct.config(state='disable')
    window.after(1,update)
    
update()
```

Adding the above code to your program will help you update your widgets (button in this case) continuously after every 1 millisecond.