# Enable or disable buttons after all widget entries are complete in tkinter

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I am making a simple GUI in tkinter to test entry validations. Most of this code appears to work, except getting the calculate button to show up enabled in green as soon as the entries are complete.
What I'm trying to achieve is that once all the entries are complete and radiobuttons are selected, the calculate button is then enabled and is visibly "available". Once the calculate button has been used the submit button is then enabled. When both buttons have been used the form resets.
I need to have both buttons in the application. Button1 (calculate) should perform some calculations AND do error checking on entry widgets. Button 2 needs to submit the data from the form to a file, but only if the validation checks were correct and the calculation has been made. I'm fairly new to python, and despite a lot of researching I cannot quite get it to work.
I think the answer in this post might help me, but I'm not completely sure how to incorporate it [How to disable the following button in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720333/how-to-disable-the-following-button-in-tkinter) .

I tried using .bind or .trace respectively with the variables for each widget, because I'd seen some examples using that method, but I got errors. I've tried various ways of enabling or disabling the buttons using .config, but essentially as a new coder I'm just having trouble even finding out what method or tool I should be using, or how to write the functions to operate as I need them.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from pathlib import Path

ws = Tk()
ws.title('Validation test')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws.config(bg='#04B2D9')
#attempts to set the button to enabled once radiobutton is chosen
def enable_calc():
    global a
    a = var.get()
    if a == 1:
        butt1.config(state=NORMAL, bg="lightgreen")
    elif a == 2:
        butt1.config(state=NORMAL, bg="lightgreen")

#calculation associated with butt1, called in validation function
def calculate(*args):
    global b
    choice = var.get()
    if choice == 1:
        a = 10
    if choice == 2:
        a = 15
    b = a * 4   
    calc.config(text=f"the amount is {b} ") 
    butt2.config(state=NORMAL, bg="lightgreen")
    butt1.config(state=DISABLED, bg="lightgrey")
    
#attempts to validate the name entry
def validation(*args):
    global select, name_check
    select = var.get() 
    name_check = name_var.get()
    msg = '' 
    butt2.config(state=DISABLED, bg="lightgrey")
#attempts to call the calculation if radiobutton selected  
    if select ==1:
        calculate()
    elif select ==2:
        calculate()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Please enter all fields ")  
        butt2.config(state=DISABLED, bg="lightgrey")
        butt1.config(state=DISABLED, bg="lightgrey")
#checks name entry for input
    if len(name_check) == 0:
        msg = 'name can\'t be empty'
    else:
        try:
            if any(ch.isdigit() for ch in name_check):
                msg = 'Name can\'t contain numbers'
            elif len(name_check) <= 2:
                msg = 'name is too short.'
            elif len(name_check) > 100:
                msg = 'name is too long.'
            else:
                msg = 'Success!'
                butt2.config(state=NORMAL, bg="lightgreen")
        except Exception as ep:
            messagebox.showerror('error', ep)  
    messagebox.showinfo('message', msg)
#writes the file (should be only if calculate was successful) and clears the widgets
def submit():
    file_sent = ""
    try:
        filepath = Path("C:/Temp/text_example.txt")
        filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        with filepath.open("a", encoding ="utf-8") as f:   
            f.write(f"\n Name : {name_check}")   
            f.close()
        file_sent = f" Success! {name_check}, your application has been submitted"
    except Exception as ep:
        messagebox.showerror('error', ep) 
    messagebox.showinfo('message', file_sent)   
    name_tf.delete(0,END)
    butt2.config(state=DISABLED, bg="lightgrey")
    var.set(0) 
#plotting components            
frame = tk.LabelFrame(ws, padx=10,pady=10)
frame.pack(pady=20)

first_name = tk.Label( frame, text='Enter Name')
first_name.grid(row=0, column=1)

calc = tk.Label(frame)
calc.grid(row=5, column=1)

name_var = StringVar()

name_tf = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=name_var,
    font = ('sans-sherif', 14))
name_tf.grid(row=1, column=1)

var = IntVar()
var.set(0)
var.trace('w', enable_calc)

opt1 = tk.Radiobutton(frame,pady=10,padx=20,
    variable=var, value=1).grid(row=2, column=1)
opt2 = tk.Radiobutton(frame, pady=10,padx=20,
    variable=var, value=2).grid(row=2, column=2) 

butt1 = tk.Button(frame,text='Calculate', pady=10,padx=20)
butt1.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)  
butt1.bind('<Button-1>', validation)

butt2 = tk.Button(frame, text='Submit', pady=10,
                  padx=25,command=submit)
butt2.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)

ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this help? Comment out line 80 #var.set(0) anddComment out line 99 #var.trace('w', enable_calc)

Comment: sort of and sort of not. I was using .set() to set the radiobuttons to all unselected, and using .trace to track changes to radiobutton choices so that the calculate button would be disabled untill all had a selection. I found that by changing this line: butt1.bind('<Button-1>', validation) to instead calling validation in the Button with command seemed to allow me to do what I wanted.